# Why does my quicksort sorts the array in a reverse order?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, quicksort

I am trying to implement a quicksort for an array of strings , but it seems that it sorts the array but in a reverse order , I wonder why is that and how can I solve this problem to sort it normally... This is my implementation :

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] list = {"a", "f", "c", "b"};
        quickSort(list, 0, list.length - 1);
        for (String s : list) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }

    private static void quickSort(String[] list, int start, int end) {
        if (start < end) {
            int pIndex = partition(list, start, end);
            quickSort(list, start, pIndex - 1);
            quickSort(list, pIndex + 1, end);
        }
    }

    private static int partition(String[] list, int start, int end) {
        String pivot = list[end];

        int leftCounter = start;
        int rightCounter = end;

        while (leftCounter < rightCounter) {
            while (list[leftCounter].compareTo(pivot) <= 0 && leftCounter < end && rightCounter > leftCounter) {
                leftCounter++;
            }
            while (list[rightCounter].compareTo(pivot) >= 0 && rightCounter > start && rightCounter >= leftCounter) {
                rightCounter--;
            }
            if (leftCounter < rightCounter) {
                swap(list, leftCounter, rightCounter);
            }
        }
        swap(list, start, end);
        return end;
    }

    private static void swap(String[] list, int start, int end) {
        String aux = list[start];
        list[start] = list[end];
        list[end] = aux;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm looking over your code, but on the topic of quicksort, there's a rather fascinating new(-ish) version called [dual-pivot quicksort](https://dzone.com/articles/algorithm-week-quicksort-three). It was recently incorporated into Java's core library. You can get the original whitepaper [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150929115744/http://iaroslavski.narod.ru/quicksort/).

Comment: Your partition's return value looks wrong.

Comment: Actually, I'm curious why you're basing your "should I swap?" conditional off of your INDEXES, not off of their VALUES. `leftCounter < rightCounter` will return return `true` if the indexes are `0` and `2` respectively, even if the values are in order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation provided in the question confuses me.  That isn't to say it isn't correct (or, at least, close to correct), but I do find it a difficult read (which is arguably more important).  It is possible that I am just slow and this implementation is actually very intuitive, but I'm leaning towards it the implementation being more clever than coherent.

In general, quicksort is a recursive algorithm that breaks a set of data into three bins relative to a pivot (less than, equal to, and greater than), then sorts the non-equal bins (using the same algorithm), and then merges the results to form a sorted dataset.  In English, it's very intuitive how it should work.  There's no reason it can't be the same in code.  I would always aim to write code that you can understand (and then make it more efficient *as necessary*), rather than to attempt to write something that you cannot comprehend and then are up the creek when it doesn't work.

Below is a more-verbose implementation that (to me, at least) seems to be more clear in its operation.  It is also highly inefficient (it makes a half a dozen different Lists and arrays just to sort a single set of data).  I don't make any apologies for this; I'm assuming this question is academic in nature.  If you do need to make it more efficient, that's an exercise to the user, but there's no reason it can't be broken down into intuitive steps, as done below (it will save you much headache).

```
public class QuickSortTest {
    private static String[] data = new String[] {"a", "b", "c", "f", "b", "e", "b"};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] sortedData = quickSort(data);
        for (String str : sortedData) {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }

    private static String[] quickSort(String[] data) {
        // Edge case: return just the data if there are 0 or 1 elements (already sorted)
        if (data.length <= 1) {
            return data;
        }

        // Initialize the return structure
        String[] sortedData = new String[data.length];

        // Choose the pivot (can be any value)
        String pivot = data[data.length - 1];

        // Initialize the bins
        ArrayList<String> lessThan = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> equalTo = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> greaterThan = new ArrayList<String>();

        // Place the data into bins (based on the pivot)
        for (String str : data) {
            int compareValue = str.compareTo(pivot);
            if (compareValue < 0) {
                lessThan.add(str);
            }
            else if (compareValue > 0) {
                greaterThan.add(str);
            }
            else {
                equalTo.add(str);
            }
        }

        // Sort the non-equal data
        String[] lessThanSorted = quickSort(lessThan.toArray(new String[0]));
        String[] greaterThanSorted = quickSort(greaterThan.toArray(new String[0]));

        // Merge the data
        int length = 0;
        for (String less : lessThanSorted) {
            sortedData[length++] = less;
        }
        for (String equal : equalTo) {
            sortedData[length++] = equal;
        }
        for (String greater : greaterThanSorted) {
            sortedData[length++] = greater;
        }

        return sortedData;
    }
}
```

As an aside, if anyone is looking to sort data in practice, just use `Collections.sort()`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your `partition` method:

```
   private static int partition(String[] list, int start, int end) {
        String pivot = list[end];

        int leftCounter = start;
        int rightCounter = end;

        while (leftCounter < rightCounter) {
            while (list[leftCounter].compareTo(pivot) <= 0 && leftCounter < end && rightCounter > leftCounter) {
                leftCounter++;
            }
            while (list[rightCounter].compareTo(pivot) >= 0 && rightCounter > start && rightCounter >= leftCounter) {
                rightCounter--;
            }
            if (leftCounter < rightCounter) {
                swap(list, leftCounter, rightCounter);
            }
        }
```

Up until this point, this is basically the standard [Hoare partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme). At the end of this loop, your list will look like `[l1, l2, ..., lx, g1, g2, ..., gy, pivot]` where `l1, l2, ..., lx` are all less than or equal to the pivot and `g1, g2, ..., gy` are greater than or equal to the pivot. `leftCounter` is pointing at `g1` and `rightCounter` is pointing at `lx`. You need to make sure that the pivot separates the two sets and that you return the correct index:

```
        swap(list, start, end);
        return end;
    }
```

These two lines are the source of your problem. You need to `swap(list, leftCounter, end)` to move the pivot to the correct spot in the list. Now your list will look like `[l1, l2, ..., lx, pivot, g2, g3, ..., gy, g1]`. You need to return the index of the pivot, which is `leftCounter`.

---

As to why it sorted in the reverse order: You got lucky. Try it on other inputs, it doesn't always sort in the reverse order.

```
String[] list = { "a", "c", "a", "b","c","f","g","a","b" }
```

> [a, g, b, a, f, c, c, b, a]

Comment: I can't help but notice that your version still misses the "if(leftCounter < rightCounter)", which will always evaluate to true...

Comment: @JasonMc92 It will not evaluate to true on the last iteration of the loop. On the last iteration, `rightCounter >= leftCounter` will not execute that `if` statement and it will exit the loop.

Comment: Ah, I did overlook at part. However, I'm still not certain that block is quite right, seeing as its comparing indices, but swapping values.

Comment: @JasonMc92 The `leftCounter` will point to the first value from the left in the array that is greater than to the pivot and the `rightCounter` will point to the first value from the right in the array that is less than the pivot. There are two cases to consider. 1)  If `leftCounter >= rightCounter`, then there is a point `p` in the middle of the array where all of the values to the left of `p` are `<=` to the pivot and all of the values to the right of `p` are `>=` to the pivot: The array is partitioned and we are done.

Comment: @JasonMc92 2) If `leftCounter < rightCounter`, then there is a value close to the left side of the array that is greater than the pivot and there is a value close to the right side of the array that is less than the pivot. Swap these two values and keep going. Eventually, we will converge in the middle with a fully partitioned array, and we are done.

Comment: Right, I think I get it now. I guess it threw me off because that's not the implementation I'm used to. (I just deleted my previous comment, because I missed something else in your explanation. I need coffee>0